# Javascript splitting between number and string with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I split following string:

```
1D11M58S
```

by means of regexp in javascript?

My result should be:

```
[1D, 11M, 58S]
```

thanks

Comment: I think I have found it 

.match( /\d+./g )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider matching vs `split`ting the string:

```
var r = '1D11M58S'.match(/\d+\D+/g);
console.log(r); //=> [ '1D', '11M', '58S' ]
```